# Add product category link on WooCommerce single product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

This code is outputting the Product (Brand) Category in (almost) the right spot - above the product title - on the Single Product Page.

How can I hyperlink it (Product Category) to the Product Category page? I essentially need to make this `<?php echo $single_cat->name; ?>` a dynamic hyperlink.

```php
/** Output Product (Brand) Category on single product page **/
function add_brand_category(){

  $product_cats = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_cat' );
  if ( $product_cats && ! is_wp_error ( $product_cats ) ){
      $single_cat = array_shift( $product_cats ); ?>
      <h3 itemprop="name" class="product_category_title"><span><?php echo $single_cat->name; ?></span></h3>
<?php }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'add_brand_category', 2 );
```

Comment: Use https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_link/ ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [wc_get_product_category_list()](https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_get_product_category_list/) – which returns the product categories in a list + adding a hyperlink to the product category page.

So you get:

```php
function action_woocommerce_single_product_summary() {
    global $product;
    
    // Is a WC product
    if ( is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' ) ) {
        echo '<h3 itemprop="name" class="product_category_title">';
        
        echo wc_get_product_category_list( $product->get_id(), ', ', '<span>' . _n( 'Category:', 'Categories:', count( $product->get_category_ids() ), 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '</span>' ); 
        
        echo '</h3>';
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'action_woocommerce_single_product_summary', 2 );
```

Comment: Thank you! This works beautifully except it prints the word 'Category' before the link. Would this be the right way to remove that? 

echo wc_get_product_category_list( $product->get_id(), ', ', '<span>' . _n( '', '', count( $product->get_category_ids() ), 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '</span>' );

Comment: @Riddle sure, just **replace** `echo wc_get_product_category_list( $product->get_id(), ', ', '<span>' . _n( 'Category:', 'Categories:', count( $product->get_category_ids() ), 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '</span>' );`  **with** `echo wc_get_product_category_list( $product->get_id(), ', ', '<span>', '</span>' );`